# PostgreSQL: change column type from boolean

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I have table *t1* and column *c1* of type boolean NULL. All values in the column are NULL. However PostgreSQL won't let me change the type of the column this way:

```
ALTER TABLE "t1"
ALTER "c1" TYPE timestamp;

* ERROR: column "c1" cannot be cast to type timestamp without time zone
```

How can I change the type? Thank you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If all the values in your columns are indeed null, simple add `USING NULL`: there's no difficult conversion to make.

```
ALTER TABLE "t1"
ALTER "c1" TYPE timestamp USING NULL;
```

Comment: Pretty sure this will merrily throw away non-null data if there is any, so do be careful.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just have to give it a time zone. This worked for me:

```
ALTER TABLE t1
    ALTER COLUMN c1 SET DATA TYPE timestamp with time zone
    USING
        timestamp with time zone 'epoch';
```

Comment: Your approach (a) doesn't use the required column type (timestamptz instead of timestamp, it's not necessarily a bad thing, on the contrary, but that's not the same as in the question) and (b) fills all the values to "epoch", which is "1-Jan-1970 00:00" instead of being null. (Try `SELECT timestamp with time zone 'epoch';`: that's what `USING` is going to use.)